# What percentage of Indonesians want secularism, libertarianism, or capitalism?

Tags: public-opinion, ideology, indonesia

What percentage of Indonesians want secularism, libertarianism, or capitalism?

Are there any surveys or statistics looking into that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General surveys are hard to come by. Secularism is hard to define exactly. If you define secular to mean "not part of a Caliphate" you would find 90% or more. On the other hand, if you ask "Do you want politicians to hold religious values?" you probably get less than 10% rejecting that idea.

I have found a [survey of high school students](http://religion-freedom-report.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/country-reports/indonesia.pdf) in Jakarta and Bandung, West Java. In the survey, 60% of the students surveyed believe that social and political affairs should be regulated, and wanted Shari‘a law to be implemented. At least 11 percent said they wanted Indonesia to be part of a caliphate.

The report I link to above notes that there is a trend towards less religious tolerance among the population.

An [article](https://suarakebebasan.org/id/dasar-libertarianisme/item/623-yang-perlu-anda-tahu-tentang-libertarianisme) ([translate](https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=en&sl=id&u=https://suarakebebasan.org/id/dasar-libertarianisme/item/623-yang-perlu-anda-tahu-tentang-libertarianisme&prev=search)) notes that "Libertarianism is misunderstood and unknown in Indonesia" This suggests that the number of Libertarians is very low.

Capitalism is also hard to define, however in the 2014 elections, all the major parties accepted a role for private ownership of the means of production, and the major secular parties identify as centrist.